# Loading a PNG image in HTML file

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my Windows Phone7.1 App Iam loading a HTML file from local path in a WebBrowser. For this I
converted a PNG Image to base64 format using the below code and the problem is base 64 format of image path is not loading the image in the webbrowser.
Please help me where i made mistake?

```
string s = "data:image/jpg;base64,";
imgStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("NewUIChanges.Htmlfile.round1.png");
        byte[] data = new byte[(int)imgStream.Length];
        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < data.Length)
        {
            int bytesRead = imgStream.Read(data, offset, data.Length - offset);
            if (bytesRead <= 0)
            {
                throw new EndOfStreamException("Stream wasn't as long as it claimed");
            }
            offset += bytesRead;
        }
        base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data);

        Stream htmlStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("NewUIChanges.Htmlfile.equity_built.html");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(htmlStream);
        string htmlcontent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        htmlcontent = htmlcontent.Replace("round1.png", s + base64);


        wb.NavigateToString(htmlcontent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no error, that `data` contains your image, and `round1.png` exist in `htmlcontent`, then it's just probably a image type error, try this:

```
string s = "data:image/png;base64,";
```